# Updating Foreign Key Tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I haven't worked with SQL in a while, and I can't seem to remember how updating foreign key tables work. Do you have to insert the element into both tables? How would I get the correct primary keys if I did it that way? I can't seem to remember, and I tried looking up some basic tutorials. The tutorials were mainly just what foreign keys were not actually inserting data into the tables.

For example if I have:

```
Table File
fileId - Primary Key
fileName - Normal column.
fileUrl - Normal column.

Table fileWord
fileId, wordId - Primary Key, Foreign Key
count - Normal column.

Table word
wordId - Primary Key
word - Normal Column
```

Do I first insert into word, then into file, and then into fileWord?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

word, fileword and then file.

```
table word has no foreign keys - safe to insert.(first/second)
table file has no foreign keys, safe to insert. (first/second)
table fileword has one foreign key referring to word - safe to insert after table word. (third)
```

Comment: I'm sorry I messed up. I fixed where I had my Foreign Keys. Do you think you could take a look at it one more time. I would just insert into File, and word first right?

Comment: yes, that is correct. file, word or word, file followed by fileword.

Comment: My only other question is how do you insert into fileword if those id's in word and file are auto incremented?

Comment: retrieve your last inserted id from file and word and then put in file word.